# .Net Core Web Application remote shared Layout or partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm making an Intranet application which will have multiple web apps managed in separate projects. There will however be common layout code such as the Intranet header/menu/footer etc.
In a single application this is done easily with the Layout page but how do I manage that in multiple applications?

I've considered pointing the _ViewStart at a remote location but that appears to only search paths local to the project.
Partial views again want local paths.
Previously I've seen this completed using a web service injecting html into the page which could possibly done using the middleware.

Am I going about this the right way or is there another solution?

Comment: Use Razor class libraries https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Never knew about these, thank you. From what I read though (correct me if I'm wrong), these are referenced in each project. If the common code needs updating, then every app that uses this dll will need re-referencing and publishing won't it? This will not be feasible as the number of apps grows. Is there not a way to pull static content through as a view?

Comment: Yes you need to recompile obviously, much like with any other reusable pieces of code (NuGet).